# Migrate with no errors, still no change to batabase

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

This is my model.

```
class Otp(models.Model):   
user = models.OneToOneField('CustomUser', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
onetime = models.CharField(max_length=25, default=calculated, unique=True)
link = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I just added the column 'link'. Workes great on my development environment.

When on my server I go inte venv and run 'makemigrations' see the changes. Then 'migrate' and everything applied.

Now when I access a page that use the table, I get 'column does not exist'.

I go inte postgres and check the table. No changes was applied. The new column is missing.

I try adding, removing forth and back. The migrations are flawless, but there are no changes to the table.

I even droppped the table. Re ran migrations to create it. It says no changes.

I'm strting to think the migrations are applying it to another database. But how can I check this. It should not be another. I only have one.

**EDIT with update on my investigation.**
My database connection is set in the settings in production.py for postgres. My development.py is sqlite.

So now I checked the db for sqlite on my server. And for sure, the migrations are applied on sqlite, not postgres.

how come it's choosing sqlite all of a sudden?

This is how I apply changes.

```
1. Make changes in models.py for app
2. Activate venv to be able to run migrations
3. Run 'python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME'
4. Run 'python manage.py migrate APPNAME'
```

So what is defining it to run migrations towards sqlite and not postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Your description does suggest that you are interfacing with a different database than you expect on your server. I'd recommend checking the [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases) setting in your Django settings file. The credentials you provide there will likely need to be different in your production and development environments.

---

In response to you most recent edit, make sure that you are running your Django instance on your server using your production settings. Based on what you have described, I assume your `wsgi.py` file includes a line resembling

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.development")
```

Django itself has no notion of development vs production settings. It only knows to load the setting module that you tell it to.

When running in your production environment, you need to *explicitly* specify the use of your "production settings". This can be accomplished most easily by  setting the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to the Python path of your settings module. Do note that this must be accomplished by the web server that runs your Django app. Simply `ssh`ing in and running `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.production` won't cut it.

A common practice is to configure your `wsgi.py` endpoint to default to the production settings, and to explicitly opt for the development settings on your local machine, e.g. via

```
$ ./manage.py --settings=myapp.development_settings <command>
```

Comment: Hi. Does it really matter when the development and production is on different machines? Shouldn't I be able to see both databses if they exist?

Comment: I don't understand how 'python manage.py migrate' knows which database I use?

Comment: @sumpen That entirely depends on how you specified you database configuration. How precisely are you accessing the DB, both the locally and on the server, and how are you issuing the migration command in both cases? You may wish to add this information to your question with an [edit].

Comment: I found out the chenges are made to sqlite and not postgres. I added more info the the post. Hope to find a way to solve this soon.

Comment: @sumpen See my recent edit regarding the detail you provided

Comment: I found the wsgi.py and wsgi.pyc. Production settings are already in the file.